AWS Lambda returns "Unsupported route" error on PUT request, but route is configured correctly
I'm trying to set up an AWS Lambda function with API Gateway to handle GET and PUT requests on the same endpoint, /userService/items, where the GET request retrieves an item by user_id, and the PUT request updates an item by user_id. However, I'm encountering a persistent "Unsupported route" error for the PUT request. The GET request works fine.
Error Message:
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "body": "\"Unsupported route: \\\"PUT /userService/items\\\"\"",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}


Test Event for PUT Request:
{
  "routeKey": "PUT /userService/items",
  "body": "{ \"user_id\": \"123\", \"name\": \"Jane Doe\", \"age\": 28 }"
}

Lambda Code:
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import { DynamoDBDocumentClient, GetCommand, PutCommand } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";

const client = new DynamoDBClient({});
const dynamo = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);
const tableName = "user";

export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  let body;
  let statusCode = 200;
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  };
  try {
    if (event.routeKey == "GET /userService/items/{user_id}") {
      const result = await dynamo.send(
        new GetCommand({
          TableName: tableName,
          Key: {
            user_id: event.pathParameters.user_id,
          },
        })
      );
      body = result.Item;
    } else if (event.routeKey == "PUT /userService/items") {
      let requestJSON = JSON.parse(event.body);
      await dynamo.send(
        new PutCommand({
          TableName: tableName,
          Item: {
            user_id: requestJSON.user_id,
            age: requestJSON.age,
            name: requestJSON.name,
          },
        })
      );
      body = `Put item ${requestJSON.user_id}`;
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Unsupported route: "${event.routeKey}"`);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    statusCode = 400;
    body = err.message;
  } finally {
    body = JSON.stringify(body);
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers,
  };
};

I have tried adding/removing any trailing slashes from the test event and route configuration to avoid mismatch issues. But why am I receiving an "Unsupported route" error even though the route keys appear to match?

can you update the event routeKey to
event.routeKey.trim() == "PUT /userService/items" to make sure that there's no extra spacing or something.
also can you just console.log(event) to fully see the content while debugging.

Hi! I've tried adding .trim() but the exact same error still persists. The body of the response is actually what I printed out
throw new Error(`Unsupported route: "${event.routeKey.trim()}"`);


if you try to update the second if condition with this: if (event.routeKey.includes("PUT /userService/items")) {   // PUT logic } . will it work?
